# Using possessive pronouns for an academic degree (e.g. my masters degree)

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessives

One of my pet peeves...people using the possessive pronoun to refer to a graduate degree. For instance, people saying I'm going to get "my doctorate" or writing "while working on my master's degree......"

There's something annoying about using the possessive pronoun in these situations, maybe it's an entitled way of claiming ownership of a degree, sometimes ones that they don't even have yet. It's very common to hear in academia, college students looking ahead and saying "when I get my doctorate degree." I don't feel that I own a doctorate degree, I have a doctorate degree.

Am I splitting hairs or technically incorrect?  and for the record I don't correct or question people when they use these possessive pronouns.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Personally, if I'd earned a doctorate (which should in theory be unique and substantially 'my' work) I'd feel that it was mine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about communication skills / politeness marking. 'Joe and I' rather than 'I and Joe'. It's probably POB, but InterpersonalSkills.SE might be willing to pronounce/advise here. // I'd just use a schwa in 'my'; I can't see a better-hedged alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One of the accepted meanings of *my* is

> used to emphasize that something belongs to or is connected with me and no one else:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/my)

That being so, I would legitimately refer to *my qualifications*, being that set of qualifications that pertains to or is connected (by academic records) to me.

It seems reasonable therefore to refer to my accredited (being a structured and formal arrangement between the university and me - only me) course of study, work and research that pertains to pursuit of a doctorate as *my* doctorate.

Answer (score 1):

Your pet peeve appears to be misplaced.

Possessives in English aren't always "an entitled way of claiming ownership", as the opening sentence of your question demonstrates. When you say "my pet peeves", you're not asserting an entitled claim of possessing that pet peeve.

Consider the following:

- My country (the country I belong to, not a country I own)
- My friends (the people I consider to be friends, not friends I own)
- My table at the restaurant (a table I'm allocated, not one I own)
- Its owner (the person who owns the dog, not the person that the dog owns)

Possessives convey association, but that association doesn't need to be one of ownership.

Using the phrase "my degree" claims association with the degree. Since one is said to "earn" a degree, there is some weight to the argument that the degree is 'owned', perhaps in the future, contingent on various factors such as passing exams. However, the major sense isn't one of ownership. Instead, it is one of narrowing the scope of awarded or anticipated qualifications to the one associated with the speaker.

As such, "my masters degree", "my doctorate", etc are completely regular uses of the possessive.

Comment: okay, thanks for taking the time here. I just need to let it go, probably "the" pet peeve is the ego involvement in all of it.  the entitlement aspect, which has nothing to do with use of the possessive pronoun, may be more "the" issue.  Good day to you.